# Add BASHPID to history?

Tags: bash, command-history

I often have multiple sessions running at any given time.  This sometimes leads to issues when trying to reconstruct work using history.  As a result, I was thinking it would be useful to include the $BASHPID somehow so that I could sort by shell and then time.  My naive attempt at this was to try

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="$BASHPID %Y %m %d - %H:%M:%S| "
```

But all this does is add the current shell's $BASHPID to the output of 'history'.

A search for HISTTIMEFORMAT and $BASHPID returned nothing.  ANy suggestions on how to get this kind of behavior?

Comment: How about adding tty?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro could you be more explicit?

Comment: if running multiple windows in a graphical shell, tty is also useful to keep an idea of what is done in several screens; or to keep a notion of what is being done by different remote users when root is being (ab)used. `man tty`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, but I don't see how that information can be stored in the .bash_history file.

Comment: Indeed, the more I understand the more I think I'll have to have multiple history files (one for each BASHPID 'cause that's more granular than tty) and then somehow process them together to make the default .bash_history file.

Comment: I send all of it to a central syslog server

Comment: another option would be to set HISTFILE to something that includes the PID as part of the filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like "bash eternal history".
There is a good [description in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533853/8017719) to get it working.

That solution is still lacking the PID, which could be added with the [ideas from here](https://debian-administration.org/article/543/Bash_eternal_history).

Mainly:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND ; }"' \
               echo $$ $USER "$(history 1)" >> ~/.bash_eternal_history'
```

Which is using the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to generate a:

```
$PID $USER $LAST_COMMAND
```

output per command executed.

Answer (score 5):

My strategy is to add to `/etc/bash.bashrc` the following line:

`readonly PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(logger -t "cmdline $USER[$PWD] $SSH_TTY $SSH_CONNECTION")'`

Then in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
*.* @syslogserver:514
```

I prefer this approach than logging to a single file, as:

- files are rotated (i.e. do not grow too much)
- the user is not able to delete his "history"
- it creates a remote log trail resistant to tampering/hacking of a server
- The rotation log in the remote syslog server can be changed to keep some months of logging
- syslog-ng allows you to have separe file logs per  logging IP address
- it is all in a central point, and you do not need to be entering multiple servers to understand what is happening
- when the remote bash session is aborted, the local history is lost, and it is not lost with this method
- also when several sessions are opened by the same user, once again all the commands do not get in history, and I get them with this method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand now that the process substitution `>(…)` is treated as the filename used to append the history to, thus: storing it.

Comment: To really improve security you need to also set as read only  `HISTCONTROL`. If the option ignorespace, a command that start with an space will **not** be logged. And keep HISTIGNORE empty to prevent that some commands are not stored.

Comment: Also, if someone executes the command `nano shtest`, that is what will be logged, only a perfectly innocuous `nano` editor, but inside the file, a simple `exec sh`, or `exec badprogram` will allow an user to avoid detection.

Comment: And, also, as the logging takes place after a command has returned to the shell (not before), the process may take actions to change the name of the process or some other mischief.

Comment: History is not (and has not been designed to be) a secure way to log what happens in a computer. It is just a helper to the user running the shell.

Comment: Indeed it is not full proof ; it is just another tool.