# Persistent command history?

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there a way to persist the command history and search it or group it by command?

In other words, I would like to list, say every grep command I have done over the last 3 months. Is that capability possible somehow?

Comment: In the C shell?  Or the Korn shell?  Or the Z shell?  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Either bash or C

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using bash which is the most common shell

```
history
```

will show you the history that is stored in your .bash_history file. You can increase the size of and add dates in the history by adding

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y/%m/%d %T "
```

To your .bashrc file. Then you can

```
history | grep " 2019/0[1-3]"
```

Note that bash only keeps history for a selection of commands in interactive sessions. If you want to track everything a custom shell wrapper, remote logging, and versioning the whole system are advisable.

Answer (score -1):

To have every command done I would not count on the bash history for several reasons. You can send such commands to the syslog service/daemon.

I used to have a backlog of 1+ year command logs performed in 200+ Debian servers, in a secure central syslog server.

I used a simple "hack" of adding in `/etc/bash.bashrc` for all users or. bash_profile just for your user the following line:

```
readonly PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(logger -t "cmdline $USER[$PWD] $SSH_TTY $SSH_CONNECTION")'
```

see related [Add BASHPID to history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375067/add-bashpid-to-history/375139#375139)

Comment: Given that we're undergoing a GAO audit, I don't don't know that I'd like like to disclose that this information is available. I'd love to see how may staff is handling problems but I don't want the security team to know that my  staff's actual commands are available for review.

Comment: @DougO'Neal The problem about using bash history is that is not reliable and not all issued commands will be there for several reasons. I talk about that in that linked U&L answer. When I did that, nobody knew, except my team lead and the IT director. It was very useful to build a case against the incompetence of a supplier and to build a case never to share again root passwords with suppliers. It was also very useful in a compromised server to established a trail of used commands in a compromised account where the command history was deleted. However, I do understand your reservations.

Comment: what about bash --noprofile --norc or some random c code?